# urllib error SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED in Python 3.7 when web scraping in windows 10

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, ssl-certificate, urllib

Im trying to get information from a page, using urllib and bs4 in python 3.7 IDE on windows 10.

When I execute the code I get the following error:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)>
```

Most of the tutorials here gave answers for Mac systems, in this case is windows.

Here is the full code:

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://carta-natal.es/astros_ahora.php'

# Grab the url and download it
uClient = uReq(my_url)

# Reads the content and storage it 
page_html = uClient.read()

# Close the connection
uClient.close()

# html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

print(page_soup.h1)
```

Comment: error not reproducible on my computer(also windows 10, python 3.7)

Comment: @SuperStormer , does that mean that it works fine for you?

Comment: yes, it works fine for me

Comment: @SuperStormer Any idea why?, i read somewhere that maybe I need to install something related to ssl?

Comment: There's a ca cert bundle that you need to download and set the path to.

Comment: @SuperStormer Is this done with a pip on the console? Or this ca cert bundle is installed in windows? Im really lost about this. Also when I try the script in other page it works.